# Getting invariant violation when using FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Hi I am trying to display data from an API in a Flatlist but I keep getting the error message that says 'Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid:expected a string(for built-in components) or a class/function for composite components but got undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it is defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render method of 'Query'.

I tried with original data and then with static DATA of JSON array of items. I also tried returning a Text element and that works but the minute I try FlatList, I get the error above. You can see the original code commented out and the test code that I tried in code snippet below.

```
render() {
        const DATA = [
            {
              id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
              title: 'First Item',
            },
            {
              id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
              title: 'Second Item',
            },
            {
              id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
              title: 'Third Item',
            },
          ];
          function Item({ title }) {
            return (
              <View>
                <Text>{title}</Text>
              </View>
            );
          }          
                const TestQuery = () => (
                   <Query query={tasksList}>
                   {({ loading, error, data, fetchMore }) => {
                     if (loading) return <Text>Loading...</Text>;
                     if (error) return <Text>Error </Text>;

                     //return <Text>{JSON.stringify(data.getAllTasksExt.items)}</Text>
                   return <FlatList
                            data={DATA}
                            //data={data.getAllTasksExt.items}
                            renderItem={({item})=> <Item title={item.title} />}
                   />
                   }
                }
                   </Query> 
                   );

                   return (
                    <SafeAreaView>
                   <TestQuery/>
                   </SafeAreaView>
                   )

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, someone runs into a similar issue. When I used FlatList, my Visual Studio Code, auto imported it from react rather that react-native. This was causing the error above. After I fixed the FlatList import, the issue was resolved.